# Remove sequence Text strip in Blender 2.80

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, effects

In 2.80 I can add a Text effect strip with the following:

```
    effName = "eff" + tCStr[-3:]
    effName = sequences.new_effect(
        name=tField,
        type="TEXT",
        channel=tChan,
        frame_start=fStart,
        frame_end=fEnd)
```

That works fine.

However, I also need to remove the strip.

I can remove Image strips with:

```
sequences.remove(image_strip1)
```

And I can remove Sound strips with:

```
sequences.remove(sound_strip1)
```

I have tried all of the following to remove the Text strips with results as shown.

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, or failing that, at least some way to do it.

**Notes:**

• effName is set to a range of values from eff000 to eff010

• tField is set to a range of values from Text0000 to Text0010

• xName is set to either effxxx or Textxxxx

```
sequences.remove_effect(xName)
```

AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'remove_effect'

```
sequences.effect_strip_remove(xName)
```

AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'effect_strip_remove'

```
sequences.remove(xName)
```

TypeError: Sequences.remove(): error with argument 1, "sequence" -  Function.sequence expected a Sequence type, not str

```
sequences.remove(eval(xName))
```

File "<'string>", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'eff000' is not defined

```
sequences.remove(eval(xName))
```

File "<'string>", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'Text0000' is not defined

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass an object of type [`bpy.types.Sequence` into `bpy.types.Sequences.remove()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Sequences.html#bpy.types.Sequences.remove). This means you can pass the return value of `sequences.new_effect()` into `sequences.remove()`. In the example in your question that reference would be stored in `effName`.

```
bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.remove(effName)
```

If you don't have a reference to the sequence anymore, you will have to retrieve it from:

```
bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all
```

---

**Update:** Since there seems to be some misunderstanding about my explanation, you find a fully functional code example below. As I said before, you need to store the return value of `new_effect()` to later us it as input for `remove()`.

```
import bpy

sequences = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences

names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
tChan = 0
fStart = 0
fEnd = 50

text_effects = []

for name in names:
    text_effect_strip = sequences.new_effect(
        name=name,
        type='TEXT',
        channel=tChan,
        frame_start=fStart,
        frame_end=fEnd
    )
    text_effects.append(text_effect_strip)

for text_effect_strip in text_effects:
    sequences.remove(text_effect_strip)
```

Comment: When I tried what you suggested i got:
TypeError: Sequences.remove(): error with argument 1, "sequence" -  Function.sequence expected a Sequence type, not str
-- 
So I tried bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.remove(eval(effName)) and got:
File "<'string>", line 1, in NameError: name 'eff000' is not defined
-- 
I assume this means I need to use: bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all
-- 
How do I do that?

Comment: I assumed that `effName` contains the return value of `sequences.new_effect` as shown in your example above. Store the return value of `sequences.new_effect` and pass that value to `sequences.remove`.

Comment: I have tried every possible iteration I can think of for sequences.remove; see the notes in my question. None of them work. What am I missing?

Comment: @batFINGER, any insight?

Comment: For clarification, I am adding anywhere from 6 to 10 text effects per scene, and am using a for loop to add the effects. I do this for two reasons: 1) it saves having to repeat the code for each text effect added (Duh!), and 2) I can vary the number of text effects added per scene. This works perfectly for adding the text effects. I just need to be able to remove them.

Comment: @mcgeo52 That doesn't really change the approach though. I have added an example to my answer that should make things more clear.

Comment: Thank you! It is working perfectly!

Comment: @mcgeo52 If this answer solved your problem, please click on the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Comment: I would be more than happy to click on a checkmark, but I don't see one. I did click on the up arrows.

Comment: @mcgeo52 No problem. It should be right below the arrows (it's grey).

Comment: It was a star, not a check mark on my browser. Found it and clicked it. Thanks again for your help.